# Async await does not wait

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise

I have the following in Typescript:

```
import sql = require("mssql");
const config: sql.config = {....
}

const connect = async() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect((err) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log("CONNECTED");
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
};

(async() => {
    await connect().then(
        () => {
            console.log("Connection pool created successfully.");
        }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
})();

console.log("Now proceeding to load...");
```

I always get the console output in the following order:

```
Now proceeding to load...
CONNECTED
Connection pool created successfully
```

What have I done wrong? How do I achieve executing the last line of code only after all the activities before it have completed execution?

Comment: Please check following link 
I hope it will helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876514/async-function-await-not-waiting-for-
promise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling the `(async () => {...` function, which is, well, asynchronous, and then directly proceed to print the loading message.

You're also mixing and matching `.then().catch()` and `async/await/catch` error handling – I'd refactor things like this:

```js
import sql = require("mssql");

const connect: (config: sql.config) => Promise<sql.ConnectionPool> = async config =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
    pool.connect(err => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      console.log("CONNECTED");
      resolve(pool);
    });
  });

const config: sql.config = {
  /*...*/
};

(async () => {
  console.log("Now proceeding to load...");
  try {
    const pool = await connect(config);
    console.log("Connection pool created successfully.");
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return;
  }
})();
```

Comment: I used that last `(async () => { ... })();` because I was struggling to execute an `await` invocation at the top level. Now I realize that won't work. I am aware your method works, but I was trying to avoid indent hell as the main code that follows in the module is huge and I was trying to achieve a "synchronous" syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(async () => {
   await connect();
   console.log("Connection pool created successfully.");
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like below

```
import sql = require("mssql");
const config: sql.config = { /*....*/ };

const connect = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                let Connection = await sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect();
                console.log("Connected to mssql");
                resolve("Successfully Connected");
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
    });
};

(async function () {
    try {
        let Connection = await connect();
        console.log("Connection pool created successfully.");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}());
```

Comment: What's the `setImmediate` helping with?

Comment: It is a callback that’s executed in the next iteration of the event loop.

Comment: Why don't you simply do: `let Connection = await sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect();` inside the `(async function () {` and avoid the `setImmediate`?  `setImmediate` is not doing any magic there.

Comment: yaa we can proceed without it